# How to use a custom GTK widget written in Vala from Python?

Tags: python-3.x, gtk3, vala

Recently i managed to make a shared library that i could use from [this](https://github.com/phastmike/vala-circular-progress-bar/blob/master/circular-progress-bar.vala) Vala file with these commands:
1:`valac circular-progress-bar.vala -X -fPIC -X -shared -o test_shared.so --library=testShared --gir testShared-0.1.gir --pkg gtk+-3.0`
2: `g-ir-compiler --shared-library=test_shared.so --output=testShared-0.1.typelib testShared-0.1.gir`

I made a simple test window in python which shows the widget and it only shows the text. Is it Python or it simply can't be used in this way ?
[Image of the test window/app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E9K7T.png)
I tried finding  function to change settings or some value but i can't find it.

I would appreciate any help given !

Comment: It should work. What is your Python code and are you getting errors on the console?

Comment: @AlThomas hello !
https://pastebin.com/HVGQEYHy
And i do not get any errors in the console.

Comment: You need to run it with like this: ```GI_TYPELIB_PATH=. LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. python3 file.py```.U can test it by making the shared library. U can literally download the Vala file and use the same

Answer (score 0):

After you've gone through the difficult technical steps of compiling an object and generating interface files to use the widget in Python, this answer may be a bit of a shock. As far as I can tell the reason no circle is showing is because the value is 0% - so no circle!

The widget has a `percentage` property and this can be set in Python with `pb.props.percentage`. In this example the percentage is set to 60% and works fine for me. I use `pb.props.percentage = 0.6`:

```py
import gi

gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk, GObject

gi.require_version('testShared', '0.1')
from gi.repository import testShared


class GUI (Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self)
        pb = testShared.CircularProgressBar()
        pb.props.percentage = 0.6
        self.connect('destroy', self.on_window_destroy)
        self.add(pb)
        self.show_all()
        Gtk.main()

    def on_window_destroy(self, window):
        Gtk.main_quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    GUI()
```

The widget has other properties that can be changed, e.g. `line_width` sets the width of the line that draws the circle.

Here is a screenshot showing the 60% and the `line_width` set to `10`:

[image: CircularProgressBar widget showing 60%]

Comment: Hello ! I appreciate the help. Sadly i don't really need the solution anymore BUT this might help others. The reason that i didn't change the percentage is because i didn't know how to do it which and also the window was a bit glitchy.